# Isomorphisms in characterisation of Galois extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

My definition of an extension $M/K$ to be Galois is that $Gal(M/K)$ only fixes things in K. I'm trying to prove that this is equivalent to $M/K$ being normal and separable.

I know that fact that if $M/K$ is normal and separable then there are exactly $d = [M:K]$ homomorphisms $j_i: M \to M$ that extend inclusion $K \to M$.

Now the proof claims that this then shows $|Gal(M/K)| = d$. However I only know how to show that the $j_i$ are homomorphisms whereas surely here we need them to be isomorphisms? I know that a field homomorphism is always injective but is there any other reason that allows us to ensure the $j_i$ are also surjective?

Thanks for any help here!

Comment: An injective linear map from a finite dimensional vector space to itself (such as $M$ over $K$) is necessarily surjective. Note that these homomorphisms are $K$ linear since they extend the inclusion map, and so are the identity on $K$.

Comment: Also is that your only question, or did you have another one?

Comment: Ah of course - thanks. I didn't notice that. That is my only question!

Comment: Great! I'll just post that as an official answer then in case anyone comes looking in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An injective linear map from a finite dimensional vector space to itself (such as M over K) is necessarily surjective.
These homomorphisms are K linear since they extend the inclusion map, and so are the identity on K.

To check this, if $a,b\in K$ and $u,v\in M$, and $\sigma$ is our map, then $\sigma(au+bv)=\sigma(a)\sigma(u)+\sigma(b)\sigma(v)=a\sigma(u)+b\sigma(v)$, since $a,b\in K$ so $\sigma(a)=a$ and $\sigma(b)=b$.